# Four arrays in for each loop

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$names= Array([0] => AdultName1 [1] => adultname2 [2] => childname1)
$passengerType =Array([0] => adult [1] => adult [2] => child)
$Lead=Array([0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] =>0 )
$childAge = Array([0] =>  [1] =>  [2] => 10)

foreach($names as $index => $name){ 
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $childAge['index'];;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}    
?>
```

Here my exctly what i need HTML code example is below format.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>PassengerType</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AdultName1</td>
        <td>adult</td>
        <td>adultname2</td>
        <td>adult</td>
        <td>childname1</td>
        <td>child(10 Years)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here my requirement is if passengerType is child need to display age from childAge

If Lead is 1 then i need to put name and passengerType into BOLD format.

Please help me , i tried not getting.

[Here Out Put Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkauP.png)

Comment: Have you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Because I'm missing what you tried, any errors you encountered... basically, how have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: i got names only , remaining out put i did not get

Comment: Thats because you have not coded anything to get the remaining output! Did you expect that data to appear by magic?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: In short  **We are very willing to help you fix problems with your code, but we don't write it for you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

define `table` tag before `for loop` and end after loop end.

and write `<?php echo $passengerType[$index].'('.$childAge[$index].' years)';?></td>` for print `passengerType and age`

```
<?php 
$names= Array(0 => 'AdultName1',1 => 'adultname2' ,2 => 'childname1');
$passengerType =Array(0 => 'adult', 1 => 'adult', 2 => 'child');
$Lead=Array(0 => 1, 1 => 0 ,2 =>0 );
$childAge = Array(0 => '', 1 =>'', 2 => 10);
?>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            PassengerType
        </td>
    </tr>

        <?php
foreach($names as $index => $name){ ?>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $name;?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $passengerType[$index].'('.$childAge[$index].' years)';?></td>
         </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>

</table>
```

Comment: I think you will find, if you look closer there is a lot more to it than this

Comment: Check his [required ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkauP.png)

Comment: `foreach($names as $index => $name){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
        <td><?php  if($passengerType[$index] =='adult'){ echo $passengerType[$index];} else {echo $passengerType[$index].'('.$childAge[$index].' years)';}?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php }`

Comment: Here i want to pass one more variable into the loop i.e $lead. If $lead=1 then display that row in bold format? how can i add one more array in to loop ?

Answer (score 1):

do you really need to work with four arrays ?

why not :

```
$people = array(
array('name'=>'AdultName1','passengerType'=>'adult','lead'=>1),
array('name'=>'adultname2','passengerType'=>'adult','lead'=>0),
array('name'=>'childname1','passengerType'=>'child','lead'=>0,'age'=>10)
);
```

it's easier to read